# String Encoding Type

Tags: string, decode, encode

I have a to decode a given string: zrun%ohduqrerwv.frp
Cant seem to figure out what type of encoding is this. I have tried multiple online services to decode the string but no solution turned up. Any type of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Caesar's Cipher.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

All letters are shifted 3 units to the left so z -> w r->o and so on..

The string decodes to:
work@learnobots.com

The tricky part is the **%** which is 5 on the keyboard, so 3 units left is a 2 which has the @ sign. That is why % translates to @. The rest is pretty simple.